# Find function given arc length

Tags: calculus, functions, arc-length

I'm creating a program that has two points and a cable hanging between them. I feel like modeling the cable using a catenary would be too hard, so I just simplified it to a parabola.

However, I'm still stuck on making sure that the length of the cable is constant. I don't know how to find a parabola (or any group of parabolas) given its arc length. The main purpose of my program isn't to model the cable, however, so if it's not possible, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Let the two points be
$$A(-a,0) \text{ and } \; B(a,0)$$
and $ L $ be the length of the cable.

We can take as the equation of the parabola
$$y=f(x)=C(x^2-a^2)$$ such that

$$L=\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}dx$$
$$=2\int_0^a\sqrt{1+4C^2x^2}dx$$

To finish, put $$2Cx=\sinh(t)$$

then

$$C=\frac 1L\int_0^a\cosh^2(t)dt$$

Remark

You can also, take instead a parabola, the more natural  curve whose equation is $$y=C(\cosh(x)-\cosh(a))$$

Comment: Thank you! However, what if the two points are not at the same y level? Also, how does y=C(cosh(x) - cosh(a)) guarantee that the arc length is constant?

Comment: @QuesoPez You will take $ y=px^2+qx+r$ .The formula $L=\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}dx$ works but the integral is a little bit more difficult.

Comment: another question, is there any reason we use the hyperbolic sine instead of the normal sine?